# href to an image label - how to jump to the image instead of the caption below the image?

Tags: floats, hyperref, positioning, links

I'm using the following command to embed images in my LaTeX document (which is then rendered as PDF)

```
\newcommand{\img}[4]{
  \begin{figure}[!hbt]
    \centering
      \vspace{1ex}
      \includegraphics[width=#2]{images/#1}
      \caption[#4]{\label{img.#1} #3}
    \vspace{1ex}
  \end{figure}
}
```

When creating a href to an image, the viewer jumps to the image caption instead of the top of the image. How do I change my `\img` command so it still puts the caption below the image but links to it jump to the image itself?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

1. You can load the package `caption`. The default setting is `hypcap=true`.
2. If you don't load the package `caption`, you can load the package `hypcap`. It is important that the package is loaded after `hyperref`. You can load `hypcap` with the option `all`. In this case `hypcap` has an influence on all float environments. You can limit it to figures by setting the option `figure`.

Comment: +1 for using `\usepackage[all]{hypcap}`