# How to refer to a figure or table and have its number printed instead of the section number?

Tags: cross-referencing

In a LaTeX document I have several figures and tables and I need to reference some of them. I tried putting the label in different positions and figured out that it worked when I put the label next to the caption. However, when the hyperlink is clicked it goes to the caption and the next table is in view which might confuse the readers of the document. Furthermore, when I put the label code after the table environment, the number displayed in the pdf is the section number (and subsection if available). How can I make the references point to the actual graphics and have their number?

EDIT: I have solved the problem by using the package "hypcap" and using the command /capstart at the point I want the "hyperref" to anchor.

Comment: You should look at adding the [`hypcap` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/hypcap) to your preamble. Keep `\label` *after* `\caption`. See [href to an image label - how to jump to the image instead of the caption below the image?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27096/5764)

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke But this given the section, subsection number instead of the figure number.

Comment: If you want to reference a float object such as a table or figure, then you must put the `\label` after the `\caption` exactly as @Werner said. Now, whn you wnt to make the crossref inside your document, then you must use the `\ref` command. I see that your problem involves also the `hyperref`package and there is the problem of the *jump* when you click over the link. That's something different.

Comment: @Werner The problem is solved by using the package "hypcap" and the command \capstart thanks for your interest.