# Bookmark tables and figures

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks

I'm trying to generate bookmarks for all Tables and Figures in a document using the code below. However, with this code, the Table 1 bookmark points to Figure 1 and the Figure 2 bookmark points to Table 2 and I cannot find why the Figure and Table numbers get mixed up.

Also, with this code, the entire caption is included in the bookmark. I would prefer to only have the short caption in the bookmark, but fail to figure out how to get the short caption. Any help with this problem would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

```
% needs two runs
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{caption}
 \usepackage{hyperref}

 \DeclareCaptionTextFormat{Tablebookmark}{\belowpdfbookmark{Table \thetable: #1}{\thetable}#1}
  \captionsetup[table]{textformat=Tablebookmark}
 \DeclareCaptionTextFormat{Figurebookmark}{\belowpdfbookmark{Figure \thefigure: #1}{\thefigure}#1}
  \captionsetup[figure]{textformat=Figurebookmark}

\begin{document}
\null\newpage

\begin{figure}[ht]
 \centering
 \rule{6cm}{3cm}
 \caption{Figure caption text}
\end{figure}

\newpage

\begin{table}[ht]
 \begin{tabular}{cc}
 Header & Header \\
 1&2\\
 \end{tabular}
 \caption[Table caption text]{This is a table with a very long caption text and it would be nice to use the short caption in the bookmark}
\end{table}

\newpage

\begin{table}[ht]
 \begin{tabular}{cc}
 Header & Header \\
 1&2\\
 \end{tabular}
 \caption{Another caption text 2}
\end{table}

\newpage

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \rule{6cm}{3cm}
  \caption{Caption text}
\end{figure}

\newpage %added two blank pages to make it easier to see bookmark targets
blank 
\newpage
blank

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bookmark should use the destination name (set by `\caption` more or less). Package `hyperref` uses `\@currentHref` to store the current destination name. In your case you have the same destination name for both the figure and table by using their numbers without further specification. Also `\belowpdfbookmark` sets a new anchor, not the optimal position, the anchor `\@currentHref` set by `hyperref/caption` is better here.

Package `bookmark` provides an easier interface to access the destination:

```
\bookmark[
  rellevel=1,
  keeplevel,
  dest=\@currentHref,
]{Table \thetable: #1}%
```

Next issue: `\caption` often sets its argument twice, because it wants to check, whether the caption fits in one line. This can be turned off with `singlelinecheck=false`. But this affects the formatting of single line captions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off}
\makeatletter
\DeclareCaptionTextFormat{Tablebookmark}{%
  \bookmark[
    rellevel=1,
    keeplevel,
    dest=\@currentHref,
  ]{Table \thetable: #1}%
  #1%
}
\captionsetup[table]{textformat=Tablebookmark}
\DeclareCaptionTextFormat{Figurebookmark}{%
  \bookmark[
    rellevel=1,
    keeplevel,
    dest=\@currentHref,
  ]{Figure \thefigure: #1}%
  #1%
}
\captionsetup[figure]{textformat=Figurebookmark}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\null\newpage

\begin{figure}[ht]
 \centering
 \rule{6cm}{3cm}
 \caption{Figure caption text}
\end{figure}

\newpage

\begin{table}[ht]
 \begin{tabular}{cc}
 Header & Header \\
 1&2\\
 \end{tabular}
 \caption[Table caption text]{This is a table with a very long caption text
 and it would be nice to use the short caption in the bookmark}
\end{table}

\newpage

\begin{table}[ht]
 \begin{tabular}{cc}
 Header & Header \\
 1&2\\
 \end{tabular}
 \caption{Another caption text 2}
\end{table}

\newpage

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \rule{6cm}{3cm}
  \caption{Caption text}
\end{figure}

\newpage %added two blank pages to make it easier to see bookmark targets
blank 
\newpage
blank

\end{document}
```

`\end{figure}` and `\end{table}` could be used as another place for setting the bookmark, if these float environments alwasy contain one `\caption`. Since package `nameref` stores the caption text in macro `\@currentlabelname`, it can be used in the bookmark:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd\endtable{%
  \bookmark[
    rellevel=1,
    keeplevel,
    dest=\@currentHref,
  ]{Table \thetable: \@currentlabelname}%
}{}{\errmessage{Patching \noexpand\endtable failed}}
\pretocmd\endfigure{%
  \bookmark[
    rellevel=1,
    keeplevel,
    dest=\@currentHref,
  ]{Figure \thefigure: \@currentlabelname}%
}{}{\errmessage{Patching \noexpand\endfigure failed}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\null\newpage

\begin{figure}[ht]
 \centering
 \rule{6cm}{3cm}
 \caption{Figure caption text}
\end{figure}

\newpage

\begin{table}[ht]
 \begin{tabular}{cc}
 Header & Header \\
 1&2\\
 \end{tabular}
 \caption[Table caption text]{This is a table with a very long caption text
 and it would be nice to use the short caption in the bookmark}
\end{table}

\newpage

\begin{table}[ht]
 \begin{tabular}{cc}
 Header & Header \\
 1&2\\
 \end{tabular}
 \caption{Another caption text 2}
\end{table}

\newpage

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \rule{6cm}{3cm}
  \caption{Caption text}
\end{figure}

\newpage %added two blank pages to make it easier to see bookmark targets
blank 
\newpage
blank

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is perfect!

Comment: As per http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27096/href-to-an-image-label-how-to-jump-to-the-image-instead-of-the-caption-below-t you can make the link point to the *image* instead of the *caption* by loading `\usepackage[all]{hypcap}` after `hyperref`

Comment: @Jon This is already done by package `caption`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Sorry, I'm in a situation where I cannot load `caption` so I didn't notice that was in your answer.