# Whether bookmarks duplicates or not is dependent on engine and `caption` package

Tags: captions, bookmarks, engine

### Backgroud

This [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/178548/79060) of question [Bookmark tables and figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/178540/79060) says

> [usage of `\bookmark` ready to be inserted]
>
> Next issue: `\caption` often sets its argument twice, because it wants to check, whether the caption fits in one line. This can be turned off with `singlelinecheck=false`. But this affects the formatting of single line captions.
>
> [first solution, using `\DeclareCaptionTextFormat` to define a new caption text format in which an `\bookmark` is inserted]

### Question

I am curious about what happens when "`\caption` sets its argument twice", so I use a simplified example and come with the following table:

```
| Engine + format | is `caption` loaded | is bookmark duplicate             |
| --------------- | ------------------- | --------------------------------- |
| xelatex         | no                  | no                                |
| xelatex         | yes                 | no                                |
| pdflatex        | no                  | only multiline captions duplicate |
| pdflatex        | yes                 | yes                               |
```

Here "duplicate" means there are two adjacent bookmarks, both having the same content and destination, in the PDF file.

- no duplicate: [image: no duplicate]
- partly duplicate: [image: partly duplicate]
- fully duplicate: [image: fully duplicate]

Hence my question is

1. Why the output is engine dependent?
   I guess this may come from the different `bookmark` driver files, but currently I am not able to read through or understand them.
   From another perspective, if every usage of `\caption` sets its argument twice (for example, inside `\@makecaption` provided by standard classes), bookmarks will always be duplicate, independent of engines.
2. For pdflatex, why the output is pacakge `caption` dependent? Which part of the source code of this package causes this?

### version info

- macOS 12.14.2 with TeX Live 2018
- XeTeX, 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999
- pdfTeX, 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19
- LaTeX2e, 2018-12-01

output of `\listfiles` with `caption` loaded and xelatex

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 caption.sty    2018/10/06 v3.3-154 Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2018/09/12 v1.8c caption3 kernel (AR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
bookmark.sty    2016/05/17 v1.26 PDF bookmarks (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2018/09/10 v0.29 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2018/09/07 v3.3 Provides the ifpdf switch
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
  ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
hyperref.sty    2018/11/30 v6.88e Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2016/05/16 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2018/11/30 v6.88e Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  hxetex.def    2018/11/30 v6.88e Hyperref driver for XeTeX
   puenc.def    2018/11/30 v6.88e Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
stringenc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.11 Convert strings between diff. encodings (HO)
rerunfilecheck.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
bkm-dvipdfm.def    2016/05/17 v1.26 bookmark driver for dvipdfm (HO)
 nameref.sty    2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
se-ascii-print.def    2016/05/16 v1.11 stringenc: Printable ASCII characters
 ***********
```

### Example document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\listfiles
\makeatletter
% simplified from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/178548/79060
\def\addBookmark#1{%
  \bookmark[dest=\@currentHref]{Figure \thefigure: #1}%
  #1%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

dummy text
\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \rule{6cm}{3cm}
 \caption{\addBookmark{Figure caption text}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \rule{6cm}{3cm}
 \caption{\addBookmark{Figure caption long long long long long long long long long long long long text}}
\end{figure}

\newpage % add a blank page to make it easier to see bookmark targets
dummy text

\end{document}
```