# Link to picture, not to the caption

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, captions, links

I have a table with some condensed information, and want to have in it links to figures (a lot), that illustrate some of the observations in the table.

Anyway, if the figures look like:

```
\begin{figure} 
\includegraphics{blah} \caption{blaaaah} \label{pic:label1} 
\end{figure}
```

then a `\cref{pic:label}` creates a link - okay - but by clicking on it the view is positioned such, that the caption is on top. (To put the `label` before `caption` is even worse - it takes the caption of the previous figure). 
Can I make the link such, that it centers on the picture and not way below. For, say, paragraphs, putting them on top of the screen is reasonable, but for figures it's rather a bug, isn't it?

Surprisingly, I didn't find such a question here yet? Do I have to create a container around the floatfigure? Can tikz help?

Comment: [href to an image label - how to jump to the image instead of the caption below the image?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27102)

Comment: thanks a lot :) it works. Strange, that I didn't see it :(

Comment: @Ilja Don't worry, it can happen. Welcome to TeX.SE! :)