# Cross-referencing pictures - show picture not its caption

Tags: cross-referencing

I have Picture X.Y:Photo1 and I am using

```
\label{pic:Photo1}
```

and

```
\ref{pic:Photo1}
```

to reference it. The outcome is something like:
...which you can see in picture X.Y.
When I click on X.Y it is supposed to display the Photo1, but there is only its caption on top of the displayed part of page and I have to scroll a bit to see the picture itself. I want the picture to be shown right after clicking on the reference. Is there a way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In your case I guess you are using `\usepackage{hyperref}`. Adding `\usepackage{hypcap}` after it should solve your problem then.

Comment: Hello, Mike. Thank you very much for your answer, however, \usepackage{hypcap} somehow did not help, so I searched the internet for information about this package and found command \usepackage[all]{hypcap}, which solved the problem for me. And next time I will post the MWE.

Comment: A brief explanation:  \label uses values set by the last \refstepcounter, which is called by \caption and automatically by hypcap.  You could just use \refstepcounter{figure} instead of \caption.

Comment: @Mike Would you like to convert your comment into an answer?

Comment: @samcarter I don't know, the answer is incomplete, the question is a duplicat (just checked), it doesn't feel right to do this.

Comment: @Mike Do you have a link to the duplicate?

Comment: @samcarter see [href to an image label - how to jump to the image instead of the caption below the image?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27096/href-to-an-image-label-how-to-jump-to-the-image-instead-of-the-caption-below-t) and its duplicate [Link to picture, not to the caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309429/link-to-picture-not-to-the-caption).