# Reference to figure with caption that includes inparaenum doesn't work correctly

Tags: captions, labels, paralist, ref

I have a problem with jumping to figure ([**not**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27096/href-to-an-image-label-how-to-jump-to-the-image-instead-of-the-caption-below-t) to the figure's caption) that has caption that includes `inparaenum`.

Minimal not working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption} % see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27102/44382

\begin{document}

Fig.~\ref{fig:test} is beatiful!

\blindtext[4]

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{test}
    \caption[]{Linux distros: \begin{inparaenum}\item Ubuntu cat, \item Linux tux, \item Android \end{inparaenum}}
    \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\blindtext[4]

\end{document}
```

(To compile the above example you need [some image](https://c1.staticflickr.com/6/5284/5266980489_fa049c7f43_b.jpg) called `test.*` – for example `test.jpg`.)

If you compile it, you'll see that jump to label doesn't work correctly unless you remove this [inparaenum](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/paralist) list:

```
\begin{inparaenum}\item Ubuntu cat, \item Linux tux, \item Android \end{inparaenum}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Works for me out of the box, the link leads to the correct image caption position By the way, you can use `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}`, this way, nobody needs the `test` file

Comment: Sorry, I didn't precise my problem. I don't want to jump to the image's caption, but to the image itself (see [similar problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27096/href-to-an-image-label-how-to-jump-to-the-image-instead-of-the-caption-below-t)). +1 for `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}`.

Comment: The problem is that `\item` does `\refstepcounter` (for possible reference to the items).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that every `\item` command does `\refstepcounter`, which sets an anchor. This anchor will supersede the one related to the image.

If you don't plan to make cross references to these items, say that `\refstepcounter` should just do `\stepcounter`. If you need cross references, you're doomed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption} % see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27102/44382
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Fig.~\ref{fig:test} is beatiful!

\blindtext[4]

\begin{figure}
\centering

\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption[Linux distros]{%
  Linux distros:
  \begin{inparaenum}
  \let\refstepcounter\stepcounter
  \item Ubuntu cat,
  \item Linux tux,
  \item Android
  \end{inparaenum}%
  \label{fig:test}%
}
\end{figure}

\blindtext[4]

\end{document}
```

Load `caption` ***before*** `hyperref`.